# How to keep displayed result before new search result display

Tags: angularjs

Due to low query result, in my AngularJS application, when I click a search button to request a new search, my page will display my pre-define error message "No related search result as you want", after one/two seconds, my query finish, my page refresh to display my new search result.

I want to keep my displayed result before new search result display?
Any suggestion or hint to do that? Thanks.

Comment: bro, attach your source code for debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes down to where you put the code to clear or replace the list of results.

It seems like you currently do something like this in your controller:

```
runSearch(searchText) {
     this.results = []; // this shows your "no results" text
     this.$http.get('/search?q=' + searchText).then(res => this.results = res.data);
}
```

Instead, just remove the first line so you only ever replace the results once the HTTP call returns:

```
runSearch(searchText) {
     this.$http.get('/search?q=' + searchText).then(res => this.results = res.data);
}
```

### Explanation

There are two points inside `runSearch` where Angular will update the page for you:

1. After the function is run, but before the HTTP call returns
2. After the HTTP call returns

Here they are in the code:

```
runSearch(searchText) {
    // #1 - any code here will update the page immediately
    this.$http.get('/search?q=' + searchText)
        .then(function (res) {
            // #2 - any code here will update the page when the HTTP call returns
        });
    // (#1 - if you have any code here it will also update the page immediately)
}
```

The technical reason for this is that Angular calls your `runSearch()` function inside a `$scope.$apply()` call, which calls your function and then runs a full *digest* of all the scopes in the application. That's what allows Angular to see the change and update the page. However, the function you pass to `.then()` on the `$http` promise executes some time later, after the initial digest completes. But Angular will *also* call this other function (the one passed to `.then()`) inside `$scope.$apply()`, which triggers another digest and allows Angular to see and apply any changes to the page at that time.

If you think about what you wanted to achieve, you only wanted to update the page *after* the search results are returned (#2 in the code above). So by only putting your code there, you got the page to update at the correct time, not before.

Comment: Thanks. What kinds of keywords will you suggest me to google to get some article to read about your solution?

Comment: @AngularJS I added some more explanation for why my solution worked. If you want further reading, look up more about the digest cycle and how AngularJS works. Once you understand that, these sorts of things become more obvious. Good luck!

Comment: I got. Thanks so much for your detailed explanation.